# What is wrong with this nodeValue replacing code?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am learning basic js operation on DOM, and it works fine with the first part of the code, which completes attributes replacing function.

Then it doesn't work with the second part code, which needs to replace the null value of the childNode.nodeValue of the "p" element.

I checked lots of times in the past 2 hrs, and the whole structure is also the same with the code in the book, but it just won't work.

I also checked the MDN about the node related entries, but also failed to get what is going on here.

gallery.js

```
function showpics(indexs){

    var linky = indexs.getAttribute("href");
    var holdy = document.getElementById("holder");
    holdy.setAttribute("src",linky);

    var texty = indexs.getAttribute("title");
    var fun = document.getElementById("funnyWords");
    fun.childNodes[0].nodeValue = texty;

}
```

Below is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
        <title>YTimes</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Our Story</h1>

        <section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../../Games/WOW/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_030815_232128.jpg" title = "F" onclick="showpics(this); return false;">F</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../Games/WOW/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_041214_150925.jpg" title = "2.0 Version" onclick="showpics(this); return false;">2.0</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../Games/WOW/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_050214_165318.jpg" title = "Riverrun" onclick="showpics(this); return false;">Riverrun</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p id="funnyWords"></p>
            <span>
                <img src="" alt="" id="holder">
            </span>
        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `#funnyWords` has no content:

```html
<p id="funnyWords"></p>
```

Therefore, `fun.childNodes[0]` is undefined.

You can create a new text node if necessary:

```js
if(fun.childNodes.length)
    fun.childNodes[0].nodeValue = texty;
else
    fun.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texty));
```

Alternatively, new browsers support [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent):

```js
fun.textContent = texty;
```

Comment: or simply `innerHTML` for crossbrowser.

Comment: @dfsq Yes, assuming `texty` doesn't have any special html character.

Comment: Thnx to the answer, though I tried all 4 methods: A, set text value to the p element； B, use the if else function above; C, use fun.textContent; D, use innerHTML. All failed in IE 11 Chrome 41 and Firefox 36. I do not know why. Does this code works fine in your browsers?

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <title>YTimes</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Our Story</h1>

    <section>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../../Games/WOW/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_030815_232128.jpg" title = "F" onclick="showpics(this); return false;">F</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../Games/WOW/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_041214_150925.jpg" title = "2.0 Version" onclick="showpics(this); return false;">2.0</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../Games/WOW/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_050214_165318.jpg" title = "Riverrun" onclick="showpics(this); return false;">Riverrun</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section>
        <p id="funnyWords">
         <div class="childnode">
         </div>
        </p>
        <span>
            <img src="" alt="" id="holder">
        </span>
    </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Since there is no child node inside "funnyWords", fun.childNodes[0] doesn't exist. so add either span or div or p element, so that you would be able to append the text to that. in the above example i have added <div class="childnode">
         </div> block of code